# How do I reorder the query result ( column interchange ) when I have a sum function in the query?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to reorder my columns in a query function that has a sum function in it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AX6iPfq5v1J-zVQCD6F5V21mwWVYQ8JQFmAHlAJnv3s/edit?usp=sharing

Link attached

Answer (score 0):

Change your formula to

```
=QUERY(A1:D12,"select B, SUM(D), C group by B,C order by sum(D) desc label SUM(D) 'SUM'", 1)
```

and see if that works?